# is it possible to get a frame from a video

Tags: wpf, video-processing

Using WPF, is it possible to access a video frame by frame.
Ideally, given a video file and time, one would get an ImageSource.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can capture frames with this library : http://videorendererelement.codeplex.com/

System should have proper codecs for that particular video format (E.g. DivX).